# WPF DataGrid navigation: ArrowUp key focusses on TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am more or less flabbergasted by the DataGrid behavior. My application has a few TexBoxes for input, combined in a Grid, and outside that Grid I have a DataGrid to show things. DataGrid style is a s follows:

```
<Style x:Key="SignalsTable" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="FullRow"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Extended"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserReorderColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeColumns" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="CanUserResizeRows" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
</Style>
```

Partial XAML of DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="MT_Raster_SignalsTable" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SignalsCollectionViewSource}}" 
          Margin="20,240,20,20" 
          Style="{StaticResource SignalsTable}"
          KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="None"
          PreviewKeyUp="SignalTableKeyUp">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
```

and the rest is columns definitions.

I just could not get 'normal' navigation with arrow keys to work (KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Continue" sometimes results in large jumps through the table when ArrowUp/Down), so I have set 'KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="None"' and attached a keyboardhandler to do things myself in SignalTableKeyUp(). That works well for Home (to top of table) and End (to bottom of table), but ArrowUp/Down still has strange behavior:

1. ArrowUp results in lost of DataGrid focus, and focus goes to a certain TexBox somewhere in the window.
2. If I click on a row twice and then hit ArrowUp, the SignalTableKeyUp() handler is called once, the SelectedIndex of the DataGrid is decraesed with one in that handler, but the selected row in the DataGrid is decreased by 2! And When I hit ArrowUp again, the TextBox receives focus....
3. If I click on a row twice and then hit ArrowDown, the SignalTableKeyUp() handler is called once, the SelectedIndex of the DataGrid is incraesed with one in that handler, but the selected row in the DataGrid is increased by 2! And When I hit ArrowDown again, the selected row increases by one (as expected).

Anybody an idea what happens here, or has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I tried some things and the solution was apperently quite simple... Now I handle the preview key down myself doing the selection change I want and then set the event to 'Handled' so that no other action is done with the keypress:

```
private void SignalTableKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Do selection stuff in DataGrid.

    // Prevent any other actions.

    e.Handled = true;
}
```